# How to hide a column in a ListView control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

How can I hide a column in a `ListView` control, without setting the column `Width` property to `0`?

Also, can I lock the `Width` of a column?

Comment: Listview is not a Grid, has limited features. I guess you can prevent Column resize or dragdrop but you can't hide and show a column except changing its Width, if you remove it and re-add it afterwards could work or not but depends on your logic.

Comment: The ListView doesn't have columns by default. Are you adding columns to the `ItemTemplate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very clear  what matters here `C++Cli` tag, but:

I presume that if you're talking about a columns in `ListView`, you're in details view of the control. There is no builtin Hide/Show column way in `ListView`, as much as I'm aware of, so one of solutions can be just remove that column form UI.

To do that in most smooth way possible just call your `ListView` column regeneration code in between

```
listView.SuspendLayout(true);

/*Manipulate column here*/

listView.ResumeLayout();
```

The data which is visible on `ListView` always remains "in your hands", so at the moment you will decide to show the column again, just show the column and fill `ListView` again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way as follows, try this code segment :

hide:

```
      LVW.Columns.Item(0).Width = 0
```

show again:

```
      LVW.Columns.Item(0).AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)
```

may this help someone.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This solution does not answer the question (which asks to not change the width to 0) but since removing a column from the list view risks causing much more work than setting the width to zero - it's still probably the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

If you need associate data with a row without displaying it use the ListView's [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag.aspx) property

Comment: -1 `Tag` is a bit of an abomination, there's only so much you can do with it. A much better way is to simply inherit from the ListViewItem class and add your own properties/fields as a real member. That way you've got a nice clean, explicit and extensible architecture.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do the Tag is fine.

Answer (score 6):

Simply just remove column at the index you wish:

```
listView1.Columns.RemoveAt(3);
```

when you want it back just insert it with its name:

```
listView1.Columns.Insert(3, "Column Name");
```

It will back with its values.

Comment: This will presumably change the subitem indexes of other columns though?

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a way to do the same thing which brought me here.

I'm not sure if there is a better way of doing it, so I use following workaround.

If you need to add a value to a `Listview` Item but don't want to show it, you can use a subitem index greater than the total column count. This way, even though the value exists it is not visible to the user.

Comment: This works perfect for me. Didn't think you could add more subitems than columns but looks like you can. I needed to have an easy way to hide file paths for each of the items so when clicked I can open that folder and this works great. DIdn't have to change any code either. Just deleted the column!

Answer (score 2):

**How to hide/show listview columns**

*C#, .NET framework 3.5.*

It is easy to hide and show listview columns, if you use the listview in “virtual mode”. In “virtual mode”, you are responsible for filling the listviewitems with data. This makes it possible to put the correct data in the correct column.

Let me demonstrate:
Create a form, and add a listview control and a button control.
Add 3 columns to the listview control.
Set the “view” property of the listview control to “Details”.
Set the “VirtualMode” property of the listview control to “True”.
Set the “VirtualListSize” property of the listview control to “100”.
Add a bool to the form:

```
private bool mblnShow = true;
```

Add the event “RetrieveVirtualItem” for the listview control, and add the following code:

```
ListViewItem objListViewItem = new ListViewItem();
objListViewItem.Text = "Item index: " + e.ItemIndex.ToString();
if (mblnShow) objListViewItem.SubItems.Add("second column: " +     DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
objListViewItem.SubItems.Add("third column: " + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
e.Item = objListViewItem;
```

Add the “Click” event for the button control, and add the following code:

```
mblnShow = !mblnShow;
if (mblnShow && !this.listView1.Columns.Contains(this.columnHeader2))   this.listView1.Columns.Insert(1, this.columnHeader2);
else if (!mblnShow && this.listView1.Columns.Contains(this.columnHeader2))
    this.listView1.Columns.Remove(this.columnHeader2);
```

Run the application, and press the button to show and hide the second column.

Please note that running a listview in virtual mode will throw an error if you put data in the items collection. There is much more the know about virtual mode, so I suggest reading about it before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit Columns (under properties of listview in design mode), under Misc set Width to ZERO

Comment: "without setting the column Width property to 0".

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one column, a second empty column shows up to fill the extra space to the right. To hide this empty column, implement the listview resize event. In there do the following.

```
m_lstItems.Columns[0].Width = m_lstItems.Width - 5;
```

This will effecitvely hide the extra empty column and instead have the first column take up all the space in the listview.

Comment: A negative value in width will always set that column to auto fill the empty area and has nothing to do with hiding a column

Answer (score 1):

You should use DataTemplateSelector to hide and show dynamically a column or a row in a listview. There is an intersting article in the official documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector