# Add / Remove columns in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Now I have a ListView in my code.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table class="global-table">
      <tr runat="server">
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
        <th>Header4</th>

      </tr>
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </table>

  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server">
      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column1") %></td>
      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column2") %></td>
      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column3") %></td>
      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column4") %></td>

    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I populate this ListView using a Data Table. (No manual additions).

Assuming I set  a  condition, for example:

```
bool isTrue = true;
if(isTrue)
{
 //Add or remove some other column
}
```

So if that condition is true, how do I add or remove columns (Both the header and content) at run time?

C# Framework :4.5.2

Comment: if you want to remove it from the data table [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75123/remove-columns-from-datatable-in-c-sharp) if from list view [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884450/how-to-remove-columns-from-listview-c-sharp) else I didn't understand your question correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the condition is given by a property of the page:

```
protected bool IsColumnVisible
{
    get { return ... }
}
```

you can use it in the markup to show/hide the column for the normal rows:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" 
    OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging"
    OnPreRender="ListView1_PreRender">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table class="global-table">
      <tr runat="server">
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
        <th>Header3</th>
        <th id="thColumn4" runat="server">Header4</th>
      </tr>
      <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server">
      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column1") %></td>
      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column2") %></td>
      <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column3") %></td>
      <td runat="server" visible='<%# IsColumnVisible %>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column4") %></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Since databinding expressions don't work in LayoutTemplate, you can show/hide the header cell in code-behind:

```
protected void ListView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.FindControl("thColumn4").Visible = IsColumnVisible;
}
```

Comment: This works for the td elements, but not for the th - Layout  Template header. Not at all sure why thats happening. I also tried setting **<th runat="server" visible="false">Header4</th>**  and even then it isn't removed from  the resultant table. (The values  are deleted and shifted by 1 to the left.). Seems like a really weird issue, as I'd expect the th elements should not be visible on setting visibility as false.

Comment: That's true. The databinding does not work for the LayoutTemplate. I modified my answer to treat that case in code-behind.

Comment: Ok. It  started working after I went for a break. I literally changed nothing, and I had made a control refresh before, and rebuilt it several times... Visual Studio just effing aroung. :/

Comment: PS:  By what I meant above when I said it worked, that wasn't because of IsColumnVisible but because of visible="false" (which didn't work before for some unknown reason). The changed answer that you gave works well. And it does hide it as needed. Thanks a ton. :) Marked the answer as the right one. I assume the other answers on this question relate to WindowsForms and not web forms. :/

Answer (score 2):

Simply just remove column at the index you wish:

```
listView1.Columns.RemoveAt(3);
```

when you want it back just insert it with its name:

```
listView1.Columns.Insert(3, "Column Name");
```

It will back with its values.

Comment: Doing this gives me the error :   **[ Error 9 'ListView' does not contain a definition for 'Columns' and no extension method 'Columns' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).  ]**  Am I missing a using reference? Didn't think I was as I  had: **using System.Web.UI; using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;** And the List View works fine.

Comment: Please refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811669/how-to-hide-a-column-in-a-listview-control

Answer (score 1):

From Code Behinde you can Insert new Item as...
Insert

```
string[] row={col1 value, col2 value, col3 value .....}
var newItem=new ListViewItems(row)
listViewItem.Items.Add(newItem)
```

Client Side.

```
 $(".row").parents("tr").append("<tr><td>col1 value</td><td>col 2 value</td><td>col3 value</td></tr>");
```

Delete 
   on ListView Event

```
 protected void listview_OnItemCommand(o as sender,e eventarg)
    {
              var row=(ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
              listView.Items.Remove(row);
    }
```

Client Side

```
 $(".row").parents("tr").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

you may add always the columns with visibility hidden and when your condition is true you change visibility for each.

The headers/columns must have the attribute runat="Server" and unique ID

Comment: Wouldn't Keeping column  visibility as hidden waste resources to send that data? In my own code it doesn't matter as much,  as I'm not exactly working on a website with massive number of people connecting,  but generally isn't  that a bad way to code?